# Streamlit multiple short videos auto play one after the other

Tags: streamlit

I have around 6 short mp4 videos on my local project path.
On Streamlit, how do I auto-play those 6 short videos one after the other. At a given time , only one video should be displayed.
[Example screenshot shown in link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33Bii.png)

Help me with sample code on how to do this on Streamlit.